# Is there a way to disable the fade in/out animations of desktop notifications?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Desktop notifications are an invaluable tool to have to be able to preview newly arrived emails without having to open up Outlook and actually open the mail.  In the office, it works perfectly fine.  However, if I were to connect to my machine remotely, the fade in/out effect of the notifications makes my remote session pretty much useless as the animations play, especially when I am outside of the network.  And if emails are coming in frequently enough, I pretty much can't do anything unless I disable notifications completely (which I do not want to do) or shut Outlook down (which I can't really do).  I just want the notification to pop in then pop out, no animations, the same way Skype for Business does its notifications.

[image]
*notification fading in and out*

Is there any way we can disable the fade effects of desktop notifications either via registry or other means?

This fade effect as far as I know has been present in all versions of Outlook from at least 2003 up to 365 for sure.  I'm currently on 365.

Comment: What version of Windows?  What version of Outlook?  Your talking about, the notification toasts, correct?  Update your question.

Comment: Yes, the notification toasts. But it applies to all versions of Windows and Outlook I have used so I didn't specify. If it's relevant, all the combinations I have had in use: XP+2003, 7+2003/365.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way we can disable the fade effects of desktop
>   notifications either via registry or other means?

No;  It is a limitation of the notification functionality within Windows itself.  You can increase length of time the notification will appear and how transparent the notification will be.

1. Open Outlook
2. Click on **File**
3. Click on **Options**
4. Click on **Mail**
5. Scroll down until you see "Message arrival"
6. Click **Desktop Alert Settings**
7. Change the **Duration** and **Transparency** of the notificaiton.

[image]

Comment: I know that, but I don't want to disable the notifications completely, just the fade effect when it appears/disappears.

Comment: You can modify the duration of the effect.  All toast notifications fade.  Outlook does not offer a feature to increase the length of time the notification is displayed longer than 30 seconds.  At the programming level, a toast notification must have a duration, so ALL application toast notifications are functionally the same.